# Rspec spec controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I no idea, how to test code like this, I want to test without Factory Bot, because it is only example:

```
class V1::ForgotPasswordsController < V1::BaseController
  skip_before_action :authenticate_user!

  expose(:verified_object) { verifier.verify(params[:token]) }
  expose(:user) { User.find_by_email(params[:email] || verified_object.first) }
  expose(:accounts) { User.by_email(verified_object.first) }

  def create
    if user
      verify = verifier.generate([user.email, 1.hour.from_now])
      UserMailer.forgot_password(user, verify).deliver_later
      render json: { message: I18n.t('forgot_password.send_instructions') }, status: :accepted
    else
      render json: { message: I18n.t('forgot_password.error_email') }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    if token_valid?
      return render json: { message: I18n.t('forgot_password.updated') }, status: :accepted unless update_passwords.include?(false)

      render json: { message: I18n.t('forgot_password.error_password') }, status: :unprocessable_entity
    else
      render json: { message: I18n.t('forgot_password.error_token') }, status: 400
    end
  end
```

end

Comment: That's why you _start_ with tests...

Answer (score 0):

There's some methods here that I can't see where they came from to properly stub, but you probably want something very close to this, that tests every code path significant to the request, and it's side effects (Sending an email):

```
require "spec_helper"

describe "V1::ForgotPasswordsController" do
  let(:user) { User.create(email: "user@example.com") }

  describe "#create" do
    context "with a valid user" do
      it "sends an email to the user and acknowledges the request as accepted" do
        expect(UserMailer).to receive(:forgot_password).with(user, anything).and_call_original
        post v1_create_path, params: { email: user.email }
        expect(response).to be_accepted
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)[:message]).to eq I18n.t("forgot_password.send_instructions")
      end
    end

    context "without a valid user" do
      it "rejects the request" do
        post v1_create_path, params: { email: "not_user@example.com" }
        expect(response).to be_unprocessable_entity
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)[:message]).to eq I18n.t("forgot_password.error_email")
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#update" do
    context "with valid token" do
      before { allow_any_instance_of(V1::ForgotPasswordsController).to receive(:token_valid?).and_return(true) }

      context "with update_passwords not including false" do
        before { allow_any_instance_of(V1::ForgotPasswordsController).to recieve(:update_passwords).and_return([]) }

        it "acknowledges the request as accepted" do
          put v1_update_path(user), params: { email: user.email }
          expect(response).to be_accepted
          expect(JSON.parse(response.body)[:message]).to eq I18n.t("forgot_password.updated")
        end
      end

      context "with update_passwords including false" do
        before { allow_any_instance_of(V1::ForgotPasswordsController).to recieve(:update_passwords).and_return([false]) }

        it "rejects the request" do
          put v1_update_path(user), params: { email: user.email }
          expect(response).to be_unprocessable_entity
          expect(JSON.parse(response.body)[:message]).to eq I18n.t("forgot_password.error_password")
        end
      end
    end

    context "with an invalid token" do
      before { allow_any_instance_of(V1::ForgotPasswordsController).to receive(:token_valid?).and_return(false) }

      it "rejects the request as bad" do
        put v1_update_path(user), params: { email: user.email }
        expect(response).to be_bad_request
        expect(JSON.parse(response.body)[:message]).to eq I18n.t("forgot_password.error_token")
      end
    end
  end
end
```